# How do I SVN copy files or projects in Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, copy, subclipse

I am working with Java projects in Eclipse (Juno), using Subclipse for version control.

I've noticed that when I copy a file or a project, the resulting copy will not be under version control.
I can add the files to version control as a second step, but that will break their Subversion history.
Usually, I want to preserve the history: I want a way to copy files and projects in Eclipse that will issue a `svn copy` command.

How can I achieve this?

*Update*: I tried it on a project again; it seems that a `svn cp` *was* issued.
In which case my question becomes: how can I *disable* that?

Comment: I tried Subclipse but in the end I just use TortoiseSvn outside of Eclipse. Right click and drag on a versioned file and choose Svn Copy or Svn copy and rename. I found Subclipse slower, less features and more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I want to make a copy of code I use the branch feature, this would keep the history intact. It is available under (Right-Click on resource) -> Team -> Branch/Tag.